# From eloquent get users that have user group 1 and 3 all not working Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi there can someone please help me I have this:

```
$users = User::where('user_group', (1 and 3))->where('deleted', 0)->get();
```

I want to take users that have user group 1 and 3 but its not working what I am doing wrong here ?!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$users = User::whereIn('user_group', [1,3])->where('deleted', 0)->get();
```

Comment: Instead, of just saying "try this", can you please explain what you fixed so they can learn from it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are wanting is all users that have user_group 1 or 3, in which case it would be more like the following.

$users = User::whereIn('user_group', [1, 3])->where('deleted', 0)->get();

Found from the Laravel Query Builder page: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

If that isn't what you are looking for, can you please explain how your table is set up so that I can help further? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Not sure if you meant users that have BOTH user_groups 1 AND 3, or just users that have user_group 1 and users that have user_group 3.

```
use App\User;

    $whereData = [
    ['user_group', 1],
    ['user_group', 3],
    ['deleted', 0]
    ];

    $users = New User();
    $users->where($whereData)->get();
```